# If $ F(a_1, \dots, a_n)$ is splitting field of a separable polynomial $f$, then $[F(a_1, \dots, a_i):F] \leq n(n-1) \cdots (n-i+1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

> Let $F$ be a field and let $E$ be the splitting field of a separable polynomial $f \in F[X]$ of degree $n$. Denote by $a_1, \dots, a_n$ the zeros of $f$ in $E$. How do we prove that, for every $i \in \{1,2, \dots, n \},$ $$[F(a_1, \dots, a_i): F] \leq n(n-1)\cdots(n-i+1), $$ and equality happens if $[E:F] = n!$?

I thought about the tower of extensions $$F \subset F(a_1) \subset F(a_1, a_2) \subset \cdots \subset F(a_1, \dots, a_i) \subset \cdots$$ and then at their degrees. As $f$ has degree $n$, it follows that $$[F(a_1):F] \leq n $$ and we can use the line of reasoning to conclude that $$[F(a_1,\dots,a_m):F] \leq (n-m+1).$$ Is this correct? However, for the equality part, I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Hint: What happens to $f$ over $F(a_1)$?

Comment: In $F(a_1),$ we have that $f(X) = (X-a_1) \cdot g(X)$. This is why I thought of the tower of extensions. The polynomial $f$ may not be irreducible and that's why $[F(a_1):F] \leq n$, and we can continue with the same line of reasoning for $F(a_1, a_2)$ and consider $g$ instead of $f$. This also implies that $[E:F] \leq n!$. So, if $[F(a_1, \cdots, a_i):F(a_1, \cdots, a_{i-1})] < n-i+1$ for some $i$, then we cannot have equality anymore, right?

Comment: Sounds to me like you have this covered.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: For the equality: if for some $i$ you have  $$[F(a_1, \dots, a_i): F] < n(n-1)\cdots(n-i+1),$$ show that you get strict inequality for all $j \geq i$. In particular you would get strict inequality for $n$